# spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams - Read Avro messages in the functional implementation

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am trying to consume messages from a topic that have been serialised in Avro. The documentation is very confusing about how this works. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_inbound_deserialization

The messages I am trying to read are avro serialised messages. I have the schema for the key and the value in the same project and have generated classes - Key and Value from the schema.

The confusion I have is, there is some unique combination of application properties and code for this to work. Right now I seem to have the wrong one and I have been trying to experiment with a bunch of properties and code combinations and none of them are working.

The error I keep getting is

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[0, 0, 0, 0, 7, -46, 15]] from topic [dbserver1.inventory.customers]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 0)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
 at [Source: (byte[])"�"; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:712)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._throwInvalidSpace(ParserMinimalBase.java:690)
```

It looks like the default json serialiser is kicking in and trying to deserialise a avro serialised message.

My code looks like below

```
@SpringBootApplication
class SpringBootKafkaConsumer {

  @Bean
  fun process(): Consumer<KStream<SpecificAvroSerde<Key>, SpecificAvroSerde<Value>>> {
    return Consumer { input -> input.foreach { key, value ->
      println("============key = $key")
      println("===========value = $value")
    }}
  }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  runApplication<SpringBootKafkaConsumer>(*args)
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: customer-balance
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            configuration:
              application:
                id: customer-balance-1
            consumer-properties:
              key.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
              value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
              schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
              specific.avro.reader: true

      bindings:
        process_in:
          destination: "dbserver1.inventory.customers"
          keySerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
          valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
          nativeDecoding: true
          startOffset: earliest
          content-type: application/*+avro

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.kafka.config: trace
```

Comment: You need to show the complete stack trace; truncated stack traces are useless.

Comment: What version of Spring Cloud Stream are you on? Since Hoxon (Horsham) RC1, there have been some significant changes in the way the bindings are created (instead of `process_1`, it is `process-in-0`). But let's start with your version and more stacktrace, hen we can see if there are issues.

Comment: Hi @sethu did you get this working, facing a similar issue?